# How do I choose a specific text box to update when a button is pressed in C#? (It's more complex than I made it sound.)

Tags: c#, textbox

So I'm writing a program that plays TicTacToe with the user and the program wins every time.
Here is my code so far:

```
namespace TicTacToe
{
    public partial class FrmMain : Form
    {
        public FrmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IdiotProof();
            PlayGame();
        }

        private void IdiotProof()
        {
            if (txtBoxTopLeft.Text != "" & txtBoxTopLeft.Text != "X")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("test");
            }
        }

        private void PlayGame()
        {
            if( txtBoxTopLeft.Text == "")
            {
                txtBoxTopLeft.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
                txtBoxTopLeft.Text = "O";
            }

            if (txtBoxBotRight.Text == "")
            {
                txtBoxBotRight.Text = "O";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that when the button is pressed both text boxes are updated to 'O'. I want it so that this is split into stages and the text box gets updated button click after button click rather than all at once. Maybe there are better ways to do this than using nine text boxes. If so please let me know.

Comment: try if, else if instead of if, if

Answer (score 2):

You want to use an `else if` rather than an `if`, so that once one of the conditions is true, no more are tested.

Comment: Duh! I should've thought of that. Thanks!